# Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7 in base_Facebook.php on line 967

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I just follow same code from [here](http://www.idiotminds.com/login-with-facebook-in-codeigniter/)

I'm getting this error frequently today. I've googled it but couldn't figure out exactly what's the root of the problem. Could be my host? Could be Facebook?

Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:20:3f07:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable thrown in ../folder/application/libraries/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 967

Comment: Apparently your server has network problems.

Comment: but the other sites on the server working fine..